# Phone number not dialing from info window from XML data

Tags: javascript, xml, google-maps-api-3

I'm working with google maps api v3 and creating a store locator with xml markers. Everything  works fine except when I click on any on a phone number from any current info window. Its only dialing the last makers phone number from the xml list . Not sure what can be causing this issue or what im doing wrong.

heres what my map looks like: http://arturoluna.com/googleMaps/snippet.html

my html

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="mapCanvas" style="width: 320px; height: 480px;"></div>
    </div>
```

my Js

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=true&libraries=places"></script>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    var infowindow;
    var map;


    function initialize() {
     // var position; 
    // Check if user support geo-location
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
        var longitude = position.coords.longitude;
        var geolocpoint = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);

            var mapOptions = {
                zoom: 12,
                center: geolocpoint,
                disableDefaultUI: true,  
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }
            // Place a marker
            var geolocation = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: geolocpoint,
                map: map,
                title: 'Your geolocation'
                // icon: icon
            });

        });
          //bounds.extend(position);
    }


    // Specify center of the map
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.713956,-73.997254);

    // Load the Google map into the #mapCanvas div
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapCanvas'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        disableDefaultUI: true,      
        center: latLng,
        zoom: 9
      });




    // Creating a LatLngBounds object
    jQuery.get("listings.xml", function(data) {
      jQuery(data).find("marker").each(function() {
        var eachMarker = jQuery(this);
        var markerCoords = new google.maps.LatLng(
            parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Latitude").text()),
            parseFloat(eachMarker.find("Longitude").text())
        );


        var name = eachMarker.find("Name").text();
        var Addr = eachMarker.find("Addr").text();
        var city = eachMarker.find("city").text();  
        var state = eachMarker.find("state").text(); 
        var zip = eachMarker.find("zip").text();  
        var phone = eachMarker.find("phone").text(); 
        var website = eachMarker.find("website").text();                  
        var html = "<div class='info-blob'>"
         +"<h1>" + name + "</h1>" 
         +"<h2>" + Addr + "</h2>" 
         +"<h3>" + city +', '+  state + ' ' + zip + "</h3>" 
         +"<h4 onclick='telFun();'>" + phone + "</h4>" + "<p onclick='webFun();'>" + website + "</p>" + "<h5 onclick='zoomOut()';>back to map</h5>" 

         "</div>";

        var marker = addMarker(html, markerCoords);

        window.webFun = function(){
          window.open('http://'+website);
        }

        window.telFun = function(){
          window.open("tel:"+phone); 
        }  

        window.zoomOut = function(){
         map.setZoom(9);
         infoWindow.close();
        }  


        });
      });
    }// end initialize();

    // Create a marker for each XML entry
    function addMarker(html, markerCoords) {
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();  
       // var Himage = new google.maps.MarkerImage("h.png",
       //      new google.maps.Size(20.0, 34.0),
       //      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
       //      new google.maps.Point(10.0, 17.0)
       //  );
       //  var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage("shadow-h.png",
       //      new google.maps.Size(38.0, 34.0),
       //      new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
       //      new google.maps.Point(10.0, 17.0)
       //  );
    // Place the new marker
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
        map: map,
        zoom: 11,
        // icon: icon, 
        // shadow: shadow, 
        center:markerCoords,
        position: markerCoords
    }); // end place the new marker

        if (marker > 1) {
         map.fitBounds(bounds);
        }
        else if (marker == 1) {
        map.setCenter(mapBounds.getCenter(marker));
        map.setZoom(15);
        }

    // Add event listener. On marker click, close all open infoWindows open current infoWindow.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
        if (infowindow) infowindow.close();
        infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({content: html});
        map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
        map.setZoom(12);
    }); // end add event listener

    // Display marker
    return marker;

      // Extending the bounds object with each LatLng


      // Adjusting the map to new bounding box
      map.fitBounds(bounds)  

    } // end addMarker();




    window.addEventListener('load', initialize, false);

    </script>
```

my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<markers>
    <marker>
        <Name>APPLE HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>1375 ROUTE 58</Addr>
        <city>RIVERHEAD</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11901</zip>
        <phone>6317270555</phone>
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>
        <Latitude>40.927732</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-72.685829</Longitude>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <Name>ATLANTIC HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>1391 SUNRISE HIGHWAY</Addr>
        <city>BAY SHORE</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11706</zip>
        <phone>6316650005</phone>
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>
        <Latitude>40.735454</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.255766</Longitude>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <Name>AUTOSPORT HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>1051 ROUTE 22 WEST</Addr>
        <city>BRIDGEWATER</city>
        <state>NJ</state>
        <zip>8807</zip>
        <phone>9087225566</phone>
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                     
        <Latitude>40.579411</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.344773</Longitude>
    </marker> 
    <marker>
        <Name>BABYLON HONDA </Name>
        <Addr>650 MONTAUK HIGHWAY WEST</Addr>
        <city>BABYLON</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11704</zip>
        <phone>6316698800</phone> 
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>         
        <Latitude>40.686089</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.344773</Longitude>
    </marker>  
    <marker>
        <Name>BARON HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>17 MEDFORD AVENUE </Addr>
        <city>PATCHOGUE </city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11772</zip>
        <phone>6314758400</phone> 
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                      
        <Latitude>40.766883</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.006502</Longitude>
    </marker>
    <marker>
        <Name>BAY RIDGE HONDA </Name>
        <Addr>8801 4TH AVENUE</Addr>
        <city>BROOKLYN</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>11209</zip>
        <phone>7188364600</phone>
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>           
        <Latitude>40.621543</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-74.028933</Longitude>
    </marker> 
    <marker>
        <Name>BREWSTER HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>899 ROUTE 22</Addr>
        <city>BREWSTER</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>10509</zip>
        <phone>8452784100</phone>
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                       
        <Latitude>41.396642</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.60527</Longitude>
    </marker> 
    <marker>
        <Name>BRONX HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>2541 E. TREMONT AVENUE</Addr>
        <city>BRONX</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>10461</zip>
        <phone>7188923300</phone> 
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                    
        <Latitude>40.843148</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.849895</Longitude>
    </marker>  
    <marker>
        <Name>CLINTON HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>1511 ROUTE 22 EAST</Addr>
        <city>ANNANDALE</city>
        <state>NJ</state>
        <zip>8801</zip>
        <phone>9087350700</phone> 
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                    
        <Latitude>40.645871</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-74.862583</Longitude>
    </marker>  
    <marker>
        <Name>COAST HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>2110 HWY 35</Addr>
        <city>SEA GIRT</city>
        <state>NJ</state>
        <zip>8750</zip>
        <phone>7329742211</phone> 
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>                    
        <Latitude>40.145289</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-74.058865</Longitude>
    </marker>  
    <marker>
        <Name>CURRY HONDA</Name>
        <Addr>3845 CROMPOND ROAD</Addr>
        <city>HEIGHTS</city>
        <state>NY</state>
        <zip>10598</zip>
        <phone>9147397600</phone>         
        <website>www.trihondadealers.com</website>
        <Latitude>41.293092</Latitude>
        <Longitude>-73.851313</Longitude>
    </marker>
<markers>
```

I only added a few xml makers from my xml list for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to how you are registering a click event listener for each marker with the corresponding details while adding a marker, you should be registering your `window.telfun` function with reference to each marker and its phone details. Currently you are overwriting it while adding each marker without any reference to the marker and finally the phone variable has the last written value, that is of the last marker from your xml. So when you click the phone number for any marker, it will be acting on the last value in your phone variable instead of the marker specific value